# Mathtools.sty not found error in TeXstudio

Tags: packages, ubuntu

I am using TeXstudio in Ubuntu 12.04. I have downloaded the `mathtools.zip` package from CTAN website. I have been through a few posts on how to install it, but couldn't understand them specifically. Please provide an step-by-step solution on manually installing the package.

Comment: Install packages by hand is not so easy. I guess that you have TeXlive installed so you can use `tlmgr` to install packages.

Comment: [The link may help you] (http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=20297)

Comment: And refresh file name database: `sudo -H mktexlsr`

Comment: Download mathtools.`tds`.zip and unzip it in `texmf-local`.

Comment: Any update here?